# Flutter resize to avoid softkeyboard is super slow

Tags: flutter

I'm building a chatting application. Somehow, when the soft keyboard appears, the widgets render very slowly. If I resize using a widget instead, it renders super fast. Is there any insight on how to fix it?

[image]

Here is flutter doctor result

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1526], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.10.2 at D:\flutter_windows_2.2.3-stable\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 097d3313d8 (4 days ago), 2022-02-18 19:33:08 -0600
    • Engine revision a83ed0e5e3
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\dangm\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
    • Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 version 16.11.31702.278
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\dangm\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • SM G977N (mobile) • R3CM70DLX9F • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows     • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1526]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 98.0.4758.102
    • Edge (web)        • edge        • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 97.0.1072.62

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: are you running on debug mode or release mode? could you post your "flutter doctor -v" as well?

Comment: It happens in both debug and release mode. I added the log from flutter doctor -v

Comment: You're using a very old version of Flutter and the latest version fixes tons of keyboard animation issues.

Comment: I updated and edited the flutter doctor. The same behavior still persist, but it seems to be faster

Comment: Are you checking that screen general framerate, memory use and views? to know if something is overly consuming memory and, therefore, damaging the framerates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem was using the old version of flutter (as Zorrilla mentioned), upgrading Flutter speed it up a lot. At the same time, the build() function is triggered repeatedly, so we need to control it more carefully